# Is there a way of Clustering in metric spaces?

Tags: java, cluster-analysis

I want to cluster data, coming from Twitter. I have users and their distances. I can not use K-means because k-means doesn't  support clustering in metric spaces. Is there an implementation for clustering in metric spaces?

Comment: It seems that there is a mismatch here between "metric" and "non-metric". Is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using hierarchical clustering for this problem?

Also here are a bunch of lectures on Clustering in metric spaces that might help:
[Clustering Large Datasets in Arbitrary Metric Spaces](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cyberia/papers/ICDE99.pdf)

[Clustering in metric spaces](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dasgupta/291/lec1.pdf)

Here are some clustering packages for java:

[ML](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/content/clustering-algorithms)

[kmeans](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/clustering/KMeansPlusPlusClusterer.html)

[Hierarchical Clustering](https://code.google.com/p/cluster-algorithms-java-alpha/source/browse/tags/rewritepending/src/algorithms/HierarchicalClustering.java?r=5)

There was a question asked over on Cross Validation that might help, they are not using java but the solution they provided might help:[Clustering with a distance matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/clustering-with-a-distance-matrix)

Comment: Hierarchical clustering scales incredibly bad. Don't try this on Twitter size data!

Comment: I wondered if an implementation already exists. I know theory, but I have no time to implement such an an algorithm from scratch!

Comment: Lefteris Bab are you fixed on Java, there are numerous clustering packages for R you could use.  But there are clustering packages out there for java you could use, I will add them to the answer.

Comment: @Alos Thank you... I use Java, but if there is something else... I could try! I tried Weka but it didn't help me to solve the problem

Comment: @Lefteris Bab how much data do you have actually?  Is the data in the form of a list or a matrix?  Thanks

Comment: @Alos I have created a parser.... Now my data have the form user1-user2,similarity. I can export them in an other format if it is neccssary

Comment: @Lefteris Bab do you have an idea of roughly how much data you will have? If it was a matrix with values what would it's size be?  I am asking because if there really isn't that much data then Hierarchical Clustering, might be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, get a book on cluster analysis.

There must be **hundreds of clustering algorithms**, many of which work on arbitrary spaces where you have some notion of similarity. As long as your notion of similarity is good, they can cluster the data. Most of the time they fail, your similarity doesn't work in the first place.

Anyway, **your question is too broad to get you a good answer**. You need to just try some of these hundred algorithms yourself.

Comment: I know that there are hundreds of clustering algorithms, I just wondered if there is any of them implemented

Comment: Yes. about 90 of them are implemented somewhere.